# What's the meaning of that $f: U\to \Bbb R^n$ is linear?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

[image: Lee83]

Let $U$ be an open set of $\Bbb R^m$. What's the meaning of that a map $f: U\to \Bbb R^n$ is linear?

Comment: Smooth manifolds? Please mention which context you got this from : if you are doing smooth manifolds without knowing what a linear map is, then please pause immediately and tell your teacher or yourself that this is like learning integration before learning integer addition. If you are not doing smooth manifolds, then tell us what you are doing, and we can clarify or provide a resource.

Comment: probably means that $f$ is a restriction of a linear map between $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1):

$$f: \Bbb R^m\to \Bbb R^n$$ is linear if and only if for all $\alpha, \beta, V_1, V_2$   we have $$ f(\alpha V_1 + \beta V_2) = \alpha f(V_1) + \beta f(V_2)$$

Such functions are also called linear transformations between two vector spaces.

Comment: Just in case anyone doesn't notice, the question was edited after this answer was posted. Originally the question had $f:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$.